# Delete line with specific number of characters

Tags: sed

I have a specific file (file.txt) with several lines.

How is it possible to delete all lines that do not have 12 characters, using sed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an interval expression to specify the exact number of characters you want to match between the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the input record.

```
sed '/^.\{12\}$/!d' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you would use `sed`.  This is much cleaner in awk:

```
awk 'length == 12' file.txt
```

Comment: did you mean `length($0)` ?

Comment: `length` with no argument uses `$0` by default.  It is probably best practice to explicitly write `length($0)`, but it's not necessary.